# Receiving ERC20 tokens

Tags: myetherwallet

I have paid for an ICO company who issue tokens into MEW, using fiat money (AUD)
I believe they will exchange the fiat for Eth when the sale ends in about 19 days time.
What they cannot advise me on is how the tokens find their way into my ETH wallet.
Do I send them a 'send to' key address to send them to or is there a different token address which I need to access so that the tokens arrive correctly.
Please advise.

Comment: They need your eth address in which they will send you tokens. Any valid ethereum address can hold ether as well as any token deployed on ethereum.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a Ethereume wallet , the best to do is myetherwallet.com(search in google how to do this).
Second, send your address wallet (it start with 0x) to ICO support for recive your tokens and tell him give you Contract address (token details) after this back to your myetherwaller web site and open your wallet and go to add token by token details.